# Ajax Login saving/not saving the username and password

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is for a hybrid app and I want to save the username and password on the phone with this code:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var get_user = localStorage.getItem("username");
    var get_pass = localStorage.getItem("password");
    username = null;
    password = null;

    if (get_user != null && get_pass != null) {    
        alert("Tem user: " + get_user + " e password: " + get_pass);
        username = get_user;
        password = get_pass; 
}
```

And I have another function on login with this:

```
$("#login").click(function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (username == null || password == null) {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        if (username.trim() == '' || password.trim() == '') {
            alert("Preenche o campo do utilizador e a password")
            return false;
        }

    var formData = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'link',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                alert(data[0].username);
                alert(data[0].nif);
                alert(data[0].datanascimento);
                alert(data[0].email);
                alert(data[0].contacto);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Utilizador ou password errados.");
            }
        }
    });
},
);
});
```

How can I do this if the username and password are set, it will call the ajax post?

Comment: My comment is predicated on your decision to store passwords in `localStorage` rather than answering your question.  Hopefully you're not storing plain text values for user credentials in `localStorage` as they are vulnerable for security purposes.  [HTML5 Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Local_Storage)

Comment: @user9263373 I'm not, I'm hashing it, just wanted to show an example